# Kentico Single image size error

Tags: c#, kentico

**Kentico Attachment Control Error:**
I am trying to upload an image on using Kentico **Attachment** form control, but i am getting a pop up "Single file size cannot exceed" error. I have made all the possible changes in web.config file related to maxRequestLenghtContent.

Do i need to enable some options in Kentico admin interface ?
or Can anyone help me to know the root cause ?

**Updated Question:**
I have included the link of image showing the error. I have made the changes that were related maxRequestLength, also added **httpRuntime maxRequestLength** tag.

**Image:**
[image]

Also even on uploading the very first files of 2KB size, i am getting the similar error related to file size.

I am saving the attachments in the Database only.

Can you provide me with possible solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to make some changes outside of Kentico depending on how big these files are.

You've looked at [`maxRequestLength` in the httpRuntime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(vs.71).aspx) which I think has a default of 4096KB.

You could also try the `maxAllowedContentLength` attribute in `system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits` (again in KB) and see if that helps you.

Do you know if you are storing files on the file system, or in the DB?  Is there anything else in the message, or just *"Single file size cannot exceed"*?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have edited my question and also provided the link of the image showing error. Can you have a look at it?

Comment: I've looked through Kentico's code for the upload control that you're using and it still all points to `system.web/httpRuntime` and the `maxRequestLength` setting.  When I get into the office, I'll see if I can replicate the issue.  Out of interest, how big is your file?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. The size of the file i am trying to upload is 1 MB and even though there is no other file attached it is giving error. I can send you my web.config code if you want to have a look at it ?

Comment: OK, it's quite concerning that the message you're getting is saying 2GB is too big for a 1MB file.  If I reduce my config settings to 1024, I can get the pop-up to display.  There are two places where `maxRequestLength` can be set:

- configuration/system.web/httpRuntime@maxRequestLength
- configuration/location[@path='cms/files']/system.web/httpRuntime@maxRequestLength

Comment: try adding the following script to the file `CMSScripts\CMSModules\AdminControls\MultiFileUploader.js` inside the `uploader.onchange` method before the first 'check' to get a view of what it thinks is going on:  `alert('MaxSize=' + maximumUploadSize + "\nBiggest=" + getMaxFileSize() + "\nTotalSize=" + calculateTotalUploadSize() + "\nNum files=" + files.length);`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for providing me the solution. It worked.

Comment: No worries, Sandy.   Next to the answer should be a check/tick.  If you click on that, it marks it as the correct solution so that people searching three same problem can find the answer a littler more quickly.

Comment: This gives you a great description on how accepted answers work: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: Thanks for explaining it, ticked the answer. Thanks so much for your time.